# How to make a pivot table with specific data type formats for each column in Excel?

Tags: google-sheets

The pivot table I want to make:

[image: The pivot table i want to make]

Using this data set:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pdkpCLZOZo06m5oWKbN4z9ZxkbAZvh61/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114832214117840988317&rtpof=true&sd=true

Not entirely sure how to get just the unit for customer returns, and just job for gift wrap etc.

Comment: The `datatables` tag refers specifically to a jQuery product for HTML tables - and therefore is not relevant here. You can hover your mouse over any tag to see a summary description. I removed the tag.

Comment: can you include example of desired output?

Comment: @player0 yes i want the pivot table the first image i showed from the dataset

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(FILTER({'Labour Hours'!B:B, 'Labour Hours'!F:F&" "&'Labour Hours'!G:G, 'Labour Hours'!H:H}, 
 REGEXMATCH('Labour Hours'!F:F&" "&'Labour Hours'!G:G, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, R6:T6&" "&R7:T7))), 
 "select sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", )
```

[image]

Comment: can yuo explain how i would do this via a pivot table please?